# Source for the Mitzvah Tanz

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, wedding, chasidut-hasidism, dance

At a Chassidishe Wedding, there is a special dance done, known as the Mitzvah Tanz. Where is the source for this dance and what is the meaning behind it? Also, why is it not done at Litvish Weddings? [Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcE0dUAMcBw) of the dance for reference.

Comment: no time to read it in depth, but the answer you're looking for will probably be found here (Nitei Gavriel, Nisuin 1, Chapter 45), especially the footnotes: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&pgnum=269

Comment: @Menachem when you have a chance, could you post this as an answer?

Comment: What makes you think that there's a source? The most you can hope for with something like this is a text that mentions the custom. But customs precede texts, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

One source is the [Machzor Vitri chelek 2:496](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10172&st=&pgnum=206&hilite=) (talmid of Rashi) at the end(last line). The custom brought was that the chosson and kallah would be danced around.It is not exactly like the mitzva tantz of today which is solely  focused on the kallah.