# Mazinka dance (dance with a broom) source?

Tags: minhag, wedding, dance

Some have a custom that, when their last child or last daughter (mazinka means youngest daughter) get married, they do a dance with a broom. Where did this come from and is it in any seforim?

Comment: Inspired by http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29971/source-for-the-mitzvah-tanz

Comment: http://torahmusings.com/2007/12/mezinke-dance/

Comment: It's a Ukrainian peasant custom that has nothing to do with Judaism https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/06/2014/mizinke-dance-tradition-folklore/ Please tell people to stop the nonsense.

Answer (score 5):

What is the source for mezinka and is it in any seforim? Technically it's in Rav Moshe Heinemann's sefer on [Hilchos Kiddushin (10:12)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0851KBW2H), but it might not be what you're looking for.

> **Q:** What’s the inyan of a mezinka?
> **A:** There is no inyan. It’s not really a Jewish custom. I have no idea
> what mezinka means other than it’s a Polish word based on a Polish
> custom. The concept is to sweep out your entire house after your last
> child is married. It’s not a universal minhag. Some people do the
> mezinka, but its source is not a Jewish minhag. If you do it, I
> wouldn’t say it’s אסור.

Comment: What a meikil !